# Get byte array of android MINI_KIND thumbnail

Tags: android, thumbnails

I am wondering if it's possible to get the byte array of android MINI_KIND thumbnail directly (Get bitmap and then encode it would work but I want to get it directly).

From Android's API http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.html

Looks like we can only get Bitmap. But hopefully there is another way to get it directly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This following code works for me. Although it return null for some images.

```
private static String getDeviceThumbnailUri(String sImagePath, Context context){
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
        String result = null;
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri("external"),
                projection, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA + " LIKE ?", new String[] { sImagePath }, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        long imageId = cursor.getLong(column_index);
        cursor.close();

        cursor = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.queryMiniThumbnail(
                context.getContentResolver(), imageId,
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND,
                null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            result = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA));
        }
        if (cursor!=null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
        return result;
    }
```